# customized list view with text view and button not support for multiple screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

In my app am using customized listed view with text view and Buttons.The screen size is 4.65" 720p(720X1280 : xhdpi),device take this resolution from layout-large folder.when i run it on device.the list view item and header display not fit to the screen like image shown below,some empty space in the end of row.Its not able to fit to the screen.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

**Header XML Coding**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/search_lay"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:background="#e8e8e8" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:text="Item(s)"
    android:textColor="#dd1713"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Price(Rs.)"
    android:textColor="#dd1713"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Qty"
    android:textColor="#dd1713"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Total(Rs.)"
    android:textColor="#dd1713"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="Fav"
    android:textColor="#dd1713"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Customized List-view XML Coding**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderlist_product_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fav_img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fav_order_list_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/special_inst_btn"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fav_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/special_inst_btn_in_orderlist"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_list_itemname"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:text="Item name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_offer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#298616"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="200.00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/orderlist_minus"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_button_click" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/order_list_quantity"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:typeface="serif" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/orderlist_plus"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plus_btn_click" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderlist_total"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="1000.00"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/orderlist_delete"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/order_list_delete" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can change to using a weighted LinearLayout if you want all the fields to have a set width in relation to the rest and that way also taking up the entire width.

Comment: @DavidOlsson when i gave the weight "1",but it calculate according to whole width.for favorite i want only small space.

Comment: Example: Set favorite to weight 1, WeightSum for instance 20 and items weight 3. Just an example, each item doesnt have to have the same weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i m giving u a demo.this layout will work on all size layout,this will definitely help u @Yugesh.
weight works percentage-wise on all screen.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="30%" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:text="20%" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:text="20%" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

further more,if there is any query,then please ask...

Comment: Thanks Rumit.your answer help me lot.